# Clean last error in R

Tags: r

I would like to clean my current R session from the last error so that a next call to geterrmessage() will be empty.

Example:

```
> stop('halt !')
Error: halt !
> geterrmessage()
[1] "Error: halt !\n"
> something_that_cleans_the_last_error
> geterrmessage()
[1] ""
```

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be no easy way. See this answer from Duncan Murdoch on R-help: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/06/02/20978.html

Answer (score 0):

Since there doesn't seem to be an easy to way to do this, here are some alternatives:

Start a new instance of R and quit the old one:

```
system("R"); q("no")
```

This will clear your workspace entirely. If you want to save your workspace, try:

```
save.image(); system("R"); q("no")
```

This restores your workspace, but will leave a lingering workspace file `.Rdata`. If you want to remove that as well:

```
save.image(); system("R"); unlink('.Rdata'); q("no");
```

But you will still have to reload any packages that you had previously loaded. That is, unless you do:

```
lp<-(.packages()); save.image(); system("R"); unlink('.Rdata'); q("no"); 
rapply(as.list(lp), library); rm(lp)
```

which only works from the command line, since the second line has to be entered into the new R shell.

Note: I don't actually recommend this solution.